# Can't assign values to angular autocomplete model

Tags: angular, autocomplete, rxjs, angular-material

**[Solved]**

I <del>have</del> had a problem with using data model in autocomplete input form (Angular 6/material).  Here is fragment of my app: [Stackblitz paste (just for general preview)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecv8cp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Both workers and pizzas list are received from JSON using the corresponding services, and then I try to apply filtered models for autocomplete.

I've set breakpoint in method getData() [app.component.ts], and variable watch tells that both workers and pizzas vars are undefined. 
Later this.workers.slice() obviously throws an exception, and it prevents autocomplete filter operation. When I resume debugging it doesn't call this method again, but data somehow is assigned, so the bottom list under my form is filled properly with data from REST API.

I tried solution that @NDDTConti provided and added some condition when valueChanges triggers, but it doesn't work as expected. So I did some more search and found this blog: [RxJS - if-else](https://blog.rangle.io/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/)

After replacing earlier value changes definition it works fine and as expected.
Edited fragment:

```
this.filteredWorkers = this.workerCtrl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map((worker) => {
      let filteredOutput: Worker[];
      if (!this.workers || !this.workers.length) {
        return filteredOutput;
      } 
      else {
        worker ? filteredOutput = this._filterWorkers(worker) : this.workers.slice()
        return filteredOutput;
      }
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that subscribe is also executed on initalization and at that time the value is null.

A simple solution would be to check if the value is null in the valueChange.

I would use something like this (this code isn't tested):

```
 this.filteredPizzas = this.pizzaCtrl.valueChanges(k => {
    if (k.startWith('') && pizzas) k.map(pizza => pizza ? this._filterPizzas(pizza) : this.pizzas.slice())
  });
```

Comment: May I ask how to do that? I'm tottaly a begginer in Angular, and don't have a clue how to check that in the valueChange method.

Comment: I added some code to my answer, even though I didn't test it, so you might have to refine it. But you will get the general idea.